# set navigation property from different schema in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm coding in C# using entity framework 5 and I have a model **Voucher** that is something like this:

```
  public class Voucher
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AppId { get; set; }

        public virtual App {get; set;}

        public int? TradeMemberId { get; set; }

        public int FiscalPeriodId { get; set; }
     }
```

I have configured this model as:

```
ToTable("Voucher", "acc");
```

So that it is mapped to:

> [acc].[voucher]

my App property is from the same database but in another schema:

> [prf].[App]

Now when ef tries to query and fill App navigation property it cannot find it in acc schema.how can i mark this property as prf schema as we do for models?any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you setup App eg, ToTable("App", "prf");

Comment: yes, already done that.

Comment: Can you please post your modelbuilder config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you proper define schema using data annotation. EF should take care of this, I have done this before and never ran into any issues.

```
[Table("Voucher", Schema = "acc")]
 public class Voucher {...}

and 

[Table("App", Schema = "prf")]
public class App{...}
```

Comment: Hes already tried this, and is using fluent not annotations see comments

Comment: Can you create a sample project with just two classes to see if it's working?